# Need help in pulling the excel data from work books VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel workbooks

1. WorkBook1 named as Week1 -> it has two worksheets Alerts & Tasks
2. WorkBook2 named as Week2 -> it has two worksheets Alerts & Tasks

Example of my Week1 file

```
1-Jan-2020 Alert-name    Description
1-Jan-2020 Alert-name    Description
2-Jan-2020 Alert-name    Description
2-Jan-2020 Alert-name    Description
```

When i loop through Week1/Week2 workbook with Worksheet named Alerts
before every date i need to add the lines as

```
1-Jan-2020 L1 Monitoring
```

I was able to loop through each work book and its worksheets.

Currently i was able to loop and consolidate the data to a single sheet, but not sure how to insert the above line before every date from the Alerts sheet

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'This is where you put YOUR folder name
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Radha\Downloads\Temp\Temp")

'Next available Row on Master Workbook
y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Loop through each file in that folder
For Each wbFile In fldr.Files

    'Make sure looping only through files ending in .xlsx (Excel files)
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then

      'Open current book
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)

      'Loop through each sheet (ws)
      For Each ws In wb.Sheets
          'Last row in that sheet (ws)
          wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

          'Loop through each record (row 2 through last row)
          For x = 2 To wsLR
            'Put column 1,2,3 and 4 of current sheet (ws) into row y of master sheet, then increase row y to next row
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 3) = CDate(ws.Cells(x, 3)) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = ws.Cells(x, 4) 'col 1
            y = y + 1
          Next x


      Next ws

      'Close current book
      wb.Close
    End If

Next wbFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test this. You will have to add the additional formatting (code, name, whatever else you want) but let's make sure this meets your needs first.

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'This is where you put YOUR folder name
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Radha\Downloads\Temp\Temp")

'Next available Row on Master Workbook
y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Loop through each file in that folder
For Each wbFile In fldr.Files

    'Make sure looping only through files ending in .xlsx (Excel files)
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then

      'Open current book
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)

      'Loop through each sheet (ws)
      For Each ws In wb.Sheets
          'Last row in that sheet (ws)
          wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

          'Loop through each record (row 2 through last row)
          For x = 2 To wsLR
          If ws.Name = "Alerts" Then
            'Put column 1,2,3 and 4 of current sheet (ws) into row y of master sheet, then increase row y to next row
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 3) = ws.Cells(x, 3) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = CDate(ws.Cells(x, 4)) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 5) = ws.Cells(x, 5) 'col 1
            y = y + 1
          Else
            'Put column 1,2,3 and 4 of current sheet (ws) into row y of master sheet, then increase row y to next row
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 3) = CDate(ws.Cells(x, 3)) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = ws.Cells(x, 4) 'col 1
            y = y + 1
          End If
          Next x


      Next ws

      'Close current book
      wb.Close
    End If

Next wbFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its not inserting the new row .its disturbing the existent data

Comment: To confirm, it's running exactly as it was before?